# How would you say "I'm done with this!" as in "I had enough"

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

I've met this phrase several times:

> "¡Basta ya!"

which from what I found translates to :

> "Enough is enough!"

But is there a more individual way of saying that you are done with doing something unpleasant or unwanted, even though you gave it a chance.

As in:

- That's it! I'm done with you!
- I'm fed up with all this!
- I had just about enough!

Comment: Relevant meta post for questions of this sort: http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1407/12

Comment: "Estoy harto" ("I'm fed", literally, but it's seldom used for food)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the examples said here express how tired or fed up you are with something/someone, but aren't saying you are definitely going to stop doing something.

If you explicitly want to say you're going to stop doing 'something', I would use any of this:

> ¡Se acabó!
>
> ¡Hasta aquí he llegado!
>
> ¡Hasta aquí!

"Se acabó" has almost the same meanings than 'I'm done' depending on the intonation, both: 'I've finished this task' and 'I'm fed up with this, I'm not doing it anymore'.

Comment: I would add to that list "Esta es la gota que colma el vaso". Is an expression I like and conveys that you have been patient long enough. Good Answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here you have some examples, but there are hundreds like this.

> Ya tuve suficiente.
>
> Paso de todo/esto/de ti.
>
> No (lo) aguanto más.
>
> Me rindo.
>
> No lo tolero más.
>
> Estoy harto de todo esto.
>
> Estoy hasta el moño.
>
> Estoy hasta la coronilla.
>
> Estoy hasta las narices.
>
> Estoy hasta el cogote.
>
> Estoy hasta la madre (Mexican Spanish)

Other adjectives:

> Cansado/asqueado/hastiado

Very rude:

> Que le den (a algo/a alguien) (+no tolero/aguanto más su...)
>
> Estoy hasta los...(órgano masculino del hombre o mujer) de ...
>
> Me cago en Dios / Me cago en todo lo que se menea.

Comment: _¿Me cago en Dios?_ ¿en qué países se expresan así?

Comment: @Mauricio En España se dice, aunque yo diría que es una expresión ya un poco desfasada.

Comment: en Cuba también se usa, igual como dice @Konamiman es un poco oldfasion, y se dice con signos de exclamación

Comment: Aclarar que ese "Me cago en" hace 20 años era un "me cago en la mar, me cago en la leche" y ha ido evolucionado hasta expresiones much más malsonantes de ese tipo: "me cago en la puta, me cago en dios, etc.". Por cierto, esa expresión sería más un equivalente de "shit!/screw them" que de "I'm done/I had enough"

Answer (score 2):

> Estoy hasta el perno.

This is probably local to Peru.  I've never heard it elsewhere.

> Estoy harto de esto.

I'm fed up with this.

Comment: Una pregunta, es malsonante (como decir "estoy hasta los huevos/cojones") o normalita ("estoy hasta las narices")

Comment: Creo que es derivado de algo malsonante.

Comment: Gracias Walter. Supongo entonces que es como "Estoy hasta el pepino", ya que aunque "pepino" no es malsonante, la expresión es simplemente una versión eufemística de "estoy hasta el rabo/la polla". Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 2):

These are some examples that I mostly hear and use:

> Ya he tenido suficiente de...
>
> Ya es suficiente...
>
> ¡Basta ya! *(or simply)* ¡Basta!
>
> Me rindo.
>
> Ya no puedo mas con *(whatever you're doing)*, me rindo.

The first one examples and adjetives provided by @AlexBcn in his answer are also valid (except the *very rude* section).

Answer (score 2):

A very (and I mean very) colloquial way would be "Me tiene podrido/a", which is argentinian/uruguayan slang. It literally means that you're rotten but it refers to being incredibly fed up/done with someone/something. You can say it to people too ("¡Me tenés podrido!") and it can also mean you're bored/tired of something ("Me pudrí de estudiar, así que me voy al cine.")

If you wanna be very improper and rude you can also say "Que se vaya a cagar/a la mierda." (Literally "Go to shit", both as a verb and as a noun). You probably know these expressions can be used with people but you can also use them to refer to a situation you're done with ("No hago más este ejercicio de matemática, que se vaya a la mierda."). Following the same idea, you can also say "Lo mandé a la mierda" as a way to express that you were tired/fed up with something/someone and so you stopped paying attention to it/doing it ("La película era muy aburrida así que la mandé a la mierda."; "Mi hermana me tenía cansado, así que la mandé a cagar."). *Remember all of these are very improper ways of talking, though.*

Now for more proper examples:

- "Me cansé de esto."
- "Me harté."
- "No puedo más."
- "No doy más." (Argentinian/Uruguayan)
- "Ya no puedo."
- "Me tiene cansado."

Answer (score 1):

In Spain, (this is a very improper way of talking, not very polite), when you are extremley fed up, for women:   "Estoy hasta el coño ya".